# Remove placeholder 0 when user starts typing

Tags: javascript, html, material-ui

I'm using Material UI's `<TextField/>` and wish to allow the user to enter floating point numbers (14.99, 10.50, 1.02). The other thing i want to do is have a placeholder that is 0 if no value is set. I managed to accomplish the latter part but now I cannot enter numbers with 0 after the decimal point (4.05 for example).

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-lgt78?file=/demo.js) is a codesandbox of pretty much what I have going on.

Here is a minimal reproducible example as well:

```
export default function TextFieldTest() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  value = Number(v).toString();

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="standard-number"
          label="Number"
          type="number"
          value={value}
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
          inputProps={{ step: 0.01, type: "number", min: 0 }}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] **in the question itself** and not only a link to an external resource

Comment: When i leave the useState() empty like "let [value, setValue] = useState();" it used the Number as placeholder and when i licked to box it automatically moved it up like you want  it. I suggest leave the useState(); empty.

Comment: Thanks, @Eren. Even after I do that, I still cannot input 1.04 for example.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you convert it from Number to string in every key change, so if you enter a number with decimals ending in 0, that's not consider part of the number itself. What's the problem of setting `v = Number(v)` directly?

Comment: If there is no value (i.e. the placeholder is "0") when you start typing it becomes 01, instead of 1.

Comment: That seems to be a known issue of React: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9402 (it occurs with `Number()` as well)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiTextField-root": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "25ch"
    }
  }
}));

export default function FormPropsTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let [v, setv] = useState(0);

  const clearPlaceholder = () => {
    if (v === 0) setv("");
  };

  const parseNumber = () => {
    if (!v) setv(0);
    setv(Number(v).toString())
  };

  // v = Number(v).toString();

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="standard-number"
          label="Number"
          type="number"
          value={v}
          onFocus={() => clearPlaceholder()}
          onBlur={() => parseNumber()}
          onChange={e => setv(e.target.value)}
          inputProps={{ step: 0.01, type: "number", min: 0 }}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```